# WPF adding stackpanel with border to grid gives error

Tags: wpf, grid, border

I'm working on a nested grid/stackpanel/grid window in WPF. Its a Calander, with a maingrid cell being a day. In this day there's a textbox and a stackpanel. The stackpanel contains a grid. EVerything is done in c#, build at run time, because the layout changes with the current month/year. No major problems sofar except when I want to add a border to a stackpanel. It gives the following error:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'ADBF.ToezAcad.Admin.OpleidingKalender.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.*

Nothing special at this position.

Funny thing is it only gives this error, the moment I add the stackpanel ( with border ) to the containing grid.

short version of the code:

```
Border stackpanelborder = new Border();
this.Content = stackpanelborder;
StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel();
stackpanelborder.Child = stackpanel;
Grid.SetColumn(stackpanel, m);                        
Grid.SetRow(stackpanel, d + 1);
mainGrid.Children.Add(stackpanel);  // if I uncomment this line, it throws the error.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Arnold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ADBF you are adding the `StackPanel` to two different child collections. Each UIElement should only have one parent in the visual tree, though a UIElement may have many children, depending on it's type.

I think you wanted to add `stackpanelborder` to the children of the `mainGrid` instead.

Edit:

Also you should be referencing `stackpanelborder` in the SetColumn/SetRow Methods not `stackpanel`.

The reason being since `stackpanel` is a child of `stackpanelborder` it will render inside the that UIElement. However `stackpanelborder` needs to be told where to insert in the grid, assuming you intend to add additional columns/rows later.

Basically your XAML document if you had one should look like this:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition .../>
        <ColumnDefinition .../> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition .../>
        <RowDefinition .../>  
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Name="stackpanelborder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ...>
        <StackPanel Name="stackpanel" .../>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Ringer! It works now. Thanks for the explanation as well. Appreciated.